# How to get multiple Reference Lists

Tags: cross-referencing, multibib

I'm trying to tidy up my dissertation I have written about coking coal. Essentially I want two reference lists, one with all the academic journals I've cited and one with all the company annual reports I've referenced. I'm trying to use multibib but it is not working well. I've tried multiple variations of the code, once I did get a separate list but they were both titled 'references'. Now I can't even get that to work. Here is my code now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcitesreports{Reports}{Miners annual reports}


something \citereports{stanmore}.
another thing \citereports{emr}.something else \citereports{rio_tinto}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}

\bibliographystylereports{plainnat}
\bibliographyreports{References}
```

References is the title of my .bib file. I'm not sure what to put in which curly brackets.
Thanks,
Oskar

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your `\newcites` has a wrong syntax. You should write`\newcites{reports}{Miners annual reports}`.